# OpenSSL 1.0.1 SSL_read() function return 0 byte on certain https Websites

Tags: ssl, https, openssl, httpclient

I'm trying to make a https client by `openssl 1.0.1u` that can visit websites with ssl protocol.
When visiting most of https websites (like google.com, yahoo.com, facebook.com, ...), it works well and the home page content is returned. However, there are certain websites (relatively small websites), the server returns me 0 bytes, here are some details:

I use `SSLv23_method()` to create my openssl context:

```
this->_sslContext = SSL_CTX_new(SSLv23_method()); // SSLv23_method: Negotiate highest available SSL/TLS version
```

Then I found that in the following calling sequence (listed forwardly):

```
(ssl_lib.c) SSL_read(SSL *s, void *buf, int num) ----> 
(s3_lib.c)  ssl3_read(SSL *s, void *buf, int len) ----> 
(s3_lib.c)  ssl3_read_internal(SSL *s, void *buf, int len, int peek) ----> 
(s3_pkt.c)  int ssl3_read_bytes(SSL *s, int type, unsigned char *buf, int len, int peek)
```

With some website (failed case), the function `SSL_read()` return 0 bytes because inside the function `ssl3_read_bytes()`, I got a `alert_descr` set to `SSL_AD_CLOSE_NOTIFY` then the function simply return 0, here is the source code:

```
...
if (alert_level == SSL3_AL_WARNING) 
        {
            s->s3->warn_alert = alert_descr;
            if (alert_descr == SSL_AD_CLOSE_NOTIFY) {
                s->shutdown |= SSL_RECEIVED_SHUTDOWN;
                return (0);
            }
```

Anyone can give me any hint to fix this problem? Thanks.

**=== UPDATE ===**

Upon [Steffen Ullrich](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3081018/steffen-ullrich)'s suggestion, I post source code that sends request / gets respone. My small experimental https client is composed of `Socket` and `SSLSocket` classes and a helper `WebpageFetcher` class. The function `WebpageFetcher::fetchPage` is used to send the https request and get the respond from private function `WebpageFetcher::_getResponse()`:

```
wchar_t * WebpageFetcher::fetchPage(wchar_t * url, int port, bool useSSL)
{
    wchar_t * response = NULL;
    Socket * socket = Socket::createSocket(false, useSSL);
    if (socket == nullptr)
    {
        response = String(L"Connection failed. Unable to create a SSLSocket!\n").toCharArray();
        return response;
    }
    if (!socket->connect(url, port))//Connection failed
    {
        response = String(L"Connection failed. Possible reason: Wrong server URL or port.\n").toCharArray();
    }
    else    //Connection succeeded
    {
        //Send request to server socket
        static const char * REQUEST = "GET / \r\n\r\n";
        static const int REQUEST_LEN = (const int)strlen(REQUEST);
        socket->send((void *)REQUEST, REQUEST_LEN); 

        //Get the response from server
        response = _getResponse(socket);

        socket->shutDown();
        socket->close();
    }
    delete socket;
    return response;
}
// ============================================================================
wchar_t * WebpageFetcher::_getResponse(Socket * socket)
{
    static const int READSIZE = 1024;   //Reading buffer size, the larger the better performance
    int responseBufferSize = READSIZE + 1;
    char * readBuf = new char[READSIZE];
    char * responseBuf = new char[responseBufferSize];
    int bytesReceived;
    int totalBytesReceived = 0;

    while ((bytesReceived = socket->recv(readBuf, READSIZE)) > 0)
    {
        // Check if need to expand responseBuf size
        if (totalBytesReceived + bytesReceived >= responseBufferSize)//No enough capacity, expand the response buffer
        {
            responseBufferSize += READSIZE;
            char * tempBuf = new char[responseBufferSize];
            memcpy(tempBuf, responseBuf, totalBytesReceived);
            delete[] responseBuf;
            responseBuf = tempBuf; //Response buffer expanded
        }

        // Append data from readBuf
        memcpy(responseBuf + totalBytesReceived, readBuf, bytesReceived);
        totalBytesReceived += bytesReceived;
        responseBuf[totalBytesReceived] = '\0';
    }

    wchar_t * response = (wchar_t *)(totalBytesReceived == 0 ?  //Generate the response as a C wide string
                            String(L"Received nothing from server. Possible reason: Wrong port.\n").toCharArray() :
                            StringUtil::charsToWchars(responseBuf));

    delete[] readBuf;
    delete[] responseBuf;

    return response;
}
```

I passed argument `useSSL` with `true` when call factory function `Socket::createSocket()` so that the socket I got is a SSLSocket instance, which overrides the default functions `connect()`, `_send()` and `_recv()` to let openssl to do the actual job. Here is the constructor of my SSLSocket class, which derives from class Socket:

```
SSLSocket::SSLSocket(bool isServerSocket, int port, int socketType, int socketProtocol, int uOptions, wchar_t * strBindingAddress, wchar_t * cerPath, wchar_t * keyPath, wchar_t * keyPass) :
    Socket(isServerSocket, port, socketType, socketProtocol, uOptions, strBindingAddress)
{
    // Register the error strings
    SSL_load_error_strings();

    // Register the available ciphers and digests
    SSL_library_init();

    // Create an SSL_CTX structure by choosing a SSL/TLS protocol version
    this->_sslContext = SSL_CTX_new(SSLv23_method()); // Use SSL 2 or SSL 3

    // Create an SSL struct (client only, server does not need one)
    this->_sslHandle = (this->_isServer ? NULL : SSL_new(this->_sslContext));
    bool success = false;

    if (!this->_isServer) // is Client socket
    {
        success = (this->_sslHandle != NULL);
    }
    else if (cerPath != NULL && keyPath != NULL) // is Server socket
    {
        success = ......
    }

    if (!success)
        this->close();
}
```

And the followings are the functions override the virtual functions in parent class Socket, which lets openssl to do the relevant job:

```
bool SSLSocket::connect(wchar_t * strDestination, int port, int timeout)
{
    SocketAddress socketAddress(strDestination, port);
    return this->connect(&socketAddress, timeout);
}
bool SSLSocket::connect(SocketAddress * sockAddress, int timeout)
{
    bool success = 
        (this->_sslHandle != NULL && 
        Socket::connect(sockAddress, timeout) &&                // Regular TCP connection
        SSL_set_fd(this->_sslHandle, (int)this->_hSocket) == 1 &&   // Connect the SSL struct to our connection
        SSL_connect(this->_sslHandle) == 1);                    // Initiate SSL handshake

    if (!success)
        this->close();

    return success;
}

int SSLSocket::_recv(void * lpBuffer, int size, int flags)
{
    MonitorLock cs(&_mutex);
    return SSL_read(this->_sslHandle, lpBuffer, size);
}

int SSLSocket::_send(const void * lpBuffer, int size, int flags)
{
    return SSL_write(this->_sslHandle, lpBuffer, size);
}
```

Comment: 1.0.1u is a VERY old version of OpenSSL (the current version is 1.1.1k, with 3.0 currently in alpha testing). The OpenSSL dev team dropped support for the 1.0.1 series at the end of 2016.  `ssl_read()` returning 0 means the server closed the TCP connection, likely because you are using such an old version.  For instance, 1.0.1 was the first version to support TLS 1.2, but your code is not using SNI, which most modern web servers require when using TLS 1.2. You need to upgrade your OpenSSL.

Comment: Hi Remy, I highly believe that your prediction is correct, because all failed cases are that when I try to visit https websites hosted on a shared web server and use kind of virtual domain. I'm very new to TLS/SSL handshake and SNI, just wondering if you could provide a link to a good tutorial? It may lead me to get the final answer.

Comment: Hi Remy, I took your suggestions and find a tutorial of SNI, then I add "SSL_set_tlsext_host_name(ssl, domainName)" before connection, and it works! I can accept your suggestion as an answer if you can post it again.